# C can't free memory after allocating it in function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

I'm working on a programm that compares the runtime and steps of insertion- and countsort.
Everything works except one thing, for countsort I have to initialize an extra array with malloc.

> My problem is that I can't figure out how or where to free the allocated memory for my `count_array`.
> (I'm fairly new to the C language)
> The malloc command is in line 47, in the "count_sort" function.

programm code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "introprog_complexity_steps_input.h"

const int MAX_VALUE = 5000000;

void count_sort_calculate_counts(int input_array[], int len, int count_array[], unsigned int* befehle) {
    // Muss implementiert werden
    int s = 0;
    *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für Zuweisung von s
    *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für Zuweisung von i
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die Überprüfung von (i < len) = true
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für i++
        s = input_array[i];
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für Zuweisung von s = input_array[i]
        count_array[s] = count_array[s] + 1;
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die Rechnung count_array[s] = count_array[s] + 1
    }
    *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die Überprüfung von (i < len) = false
}

void count_sort_write_output_array(int output_array[], int len, int count_array[], unsigned int* befehle) {
    // Muss implementiert werden
    int k = 0;
    *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für Zuweisung von k
    *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für Zuweisung von j
    *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für Zuweisung von i
    for(int j = 0; j <= MAX_VALUE; j++){
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die Überprüfung von (j <= MAX_VALUE) = true
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für j++
        for(int i = 0; i < count_array[j]; i++){
            *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die Überprüfung von (i < count_array[j]) = true
            *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für i++
            output_array[k] = j;
            *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für Zuweisung von output_array[k] = j
            k = k + 1;
            *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die Rechnung k = k + 1
        }        
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die Überprüfung von (i < count_array[j]) = false
    }
    *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die Überprüfung von (j <= MAX_VALUE) = false
}

void count_sort(int array[], int len, unsigned int* befehle) {
    // Muss implementiert werden
    int* count_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX_VALUE);
    
    count_sort_calculate_counts(array, len, count_array, befehle);   
    count_sort_write_output_array(array, len, count_array, befehle);

}


void insertion_sort(int array[], int len, unsigned int* befehle) {
    // Muss implementiert werden
    int key;
    int i;
    *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für Zuweisung von key
    *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für Zuweisung von i
    *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für Zuweisung von j
    for (int j = 1; j <len; j++){
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die Überprüfung von (j <len) = true
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für j++
        i = j;
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die zuweisung i = j;
        key = array[j];
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die zuweisung key = array[j]
        i = j - 1;
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die Rechnung i = j - 1
        while (i >= 0 && array[i] > key){
            *befehle = *befehle + 2; //2 Befehle für die Bedingungen (i >= 0 = true) und (array[i] > key) = true
            array[i + 1] = array[i];
            *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die zuweisung array[i + 1] = array[i]
            i = i - 1;
            *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die Rechnung i = i - 1;
        }
        *befehle = *befehle + 2; //2 Befehle für die Bedingung (i >= 0 = false) und (array[i] > key) = false
        array[i+1] = key;
        *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die zuweisung array[i+1] = key
    }
    *befehle = *befehle + 1; //1 Befehl für die Überprüfung von (j <len) = false
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const int WERTE[] = {10000,20000,30000,40000,50000};
    const int LEN_WERTE = 5;
    const int LEN_ALGORITHMEN = 2;

    int rc = 0;
    unsigned int befehle_array[LEN_ALGORITHMEN][LEN_WERTE];
    double laufzeit_array[LEN_ALGORITHMEN][LEN_WERTE];

    for(int j = 0; j < LEN_WERTE; ++j) {
        int n = WERTE[j];

        // Reserviere Speicher für  Arrays der Länge n
        int* array_countsort = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
        int* array_insertionsort = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
        
        
        // Fülle array_countsort mit Zufallswerten ..
        fill_array_randomly(array_countsort, n, MAX_VALUE);
        // ... und kopiere die erzeugten Werte in das Array
        // array_insertionsort
        copy_array_elements(array_insertionsort, array_countsort, n);

        // Teste ob beide Arrays auch wirklich die gleichen Werte
        // enthalten
        if(!check_equality_of_arrays(array_countsort, array_insertionsort, n)) {
            printf("Die Eingaben für beide Algorithmen müssen für die Vergleichbarkeit gleich sein!\n");
            return -1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < LEN_ALGORITHMEN; ++i) {
            unsigned int anzahl_befehle = 0;

            start_timer();

            // Aufruf der entsprechenden Sortieralgorithmen
            if(i==0) {
                    count_sort(array_countsort, n, &anzahl_befehle);
            } else if(i==1) {
                    insertion_sort(array_insertionsort, n, &anzahl_befehle);
            }

            // Speichere die Laufzeit sowie die Anzahl benötigter
            // Befehle
            laufzeit_array[i][j] = end_timer();
            befehle_array[i][j] = anzahl_befehle;
        }

        
        // Teste, ob die Ausgabe beider Algorithmen gleich sind
        if(!check_equality_of_arrays(array_countsort, array_insertionsort, n)) {
            printf("Die Arrays sind nicht gleich. Eines muss (falsch) sortiert worden sein!\n");
            rc = -1;
        }

        // Gib den Speicherplatz wieder frei
        free(array_countsort);
        free(array_insertionsort);
    }

    // Ausgabe der Anzahl ausgeführter Befehle sowie der gemessenen
    // Laufzeiten (in Millisekunden)
    printf("Parameter MAX_VALUE hat den Wert %d\n", MAX_VALUE);
    printf("\t %32s           %32s \n", "Countsort","Insertionsort");
    printf("%8s \t %16s %16s \t %16s %16s \n", "n","Befehle", "Laufzeit","Befehle","Laufzeit");

    for(int j = 0; j < LEN_WERTE; ++j) {
        printf("%8d \t ",WERTE[j]);
        for(int i = 0; i < LEN_ALGORITHMEN; ++i) {
            printf("%16u %16.4f \t ",  befehle_array[i][j], laufzeit_array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return rc;
}
```

I have tried to free the memory of the count array at several points of the programm. Compiling works but if I run the programm it spits out a segmentation fault.

Also I have tried to not use the malloc command and just use

```
int count_array[MAX_VALUE];
```

which also gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: run it under valgrind

Comment: Free it when you're done using it.  Definitely no sooner, and preferably not too much after.  If you understand your own code, then you will know when you're done with the array.  Free it there.

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j <= MAX_VALUE; j++){` probably should be `for( int j = 0;  j < MAX_VALUE;  j++){` That is a common off by one error that results in an out of bounds access. It will access count_array out of bounds.

Comment: The reason you're getting a segmentation fault is because 5000000 is too big for an array on the stack. Do you really need such a big array?

Comment: `array[i + 1] = array[i];` will access outside the array when `i` is the last index of the array.

Comment: `free(count_array)` should be at the end of `count_sort()`. The array isn't saved by either of the functions it calls, so free it after you're done using it.

Comment: That's also what i thought, but i get a segmentation error if I free count_attay at the end if countsort(). So confusing for me :/

Comment: Then you are abusing the memory elsewhere in either or both of the functions called from `count_sort()`.  You must be writing out of bounds and corrupting the memory allocation control information.

Comment: @weito be aware that once you've accessed beyond the bounds of an array (dynamically allocated or not) all bets are off, anything can happen like your program crashing immediately, your program crashing later in an apparently unrelated part or your code, or it might just appear to work fine. Google _undefined behaviour C_.

Comment: ```==1291== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)```
that valgrind line should tell me that something is out of bounds right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As @AviBerger pointed out, it may be because you are accessing `count_array[MAX_VALUE]`, whereas the last element legally accessable is `MAX_VALUE-1`.
2. Make sure that `fill_array_randomly` function only fills non-negative integers to the array, cause in the function `count_sort_calculate_counts`, in the statement `count_array[s] = count_array[s] + 1;`, you are accessing `input_array[i]`th element of count_array, and if `input_array[i]` is negative, then it may issue this error.

Comment: 3. I had to fill the count array with int numbers before using it.
<
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++) count_array[i] = 0;
>

Comment: @weito you could use calloc